# Windows 7 Pro 64Bit... now thinks it's a 16Bit OS? I can't "repair" Windows or MS Office suite?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2013

**Question :**
What software tools can repair Windows 7 Pro 64Bit, when it has been damaged (ie. it thinks it is a 16Bit OS and won't repair from Win7 install disk). 
*NOTE : When trying to avoid a complete re-install/rebuild of the whole system. System = Windows 7 Pro 64Bit, OEM, Part No.: X15-37362, with licenced CD provided by retailer.*

---

**Summary of issue :**
After some Windows 7 OS & Office problems, I went to use the Windows install disk "Repair" option (on install CD). I get CD "booting" up to the install window, and it shows the Repair option. I try "repair"...

Unfortunately, I don't have the exact error message wording, but essentially it said something like "You can't repair Windows 7 64 Bit on your 16 Bit windows OS" (definitely it referenced 16-bit OS).

Additionally, I read much about trying Bootsec.exe file, but this only seems to be available if you can get to the Repair module on the install disk (and go to the Command window option)... but, I don't get that far.

I'm trying to find a solution of how to repair this Windows 7 system, but can't locate anything on internet so far?

More details follow, if anyone has seen error/behaviour before...

---

**It started (I think) by... :**
My Windows 7 (Pro 64Bit, OEM, Part No.: X15-37362, with licenced CD provided by retailer) system drive (C:) was down to 34MB (yeah, I know)... so took evasive action to move data files off full SSD. I used the Properties settings for "moving" my default locations of My Pictures, My Documents, etc to a secondary drive. Great, got back to about 6GB and although not perfect, it's enough to get me going again. (Left for home after this, with computer still on and just sitting there).

---

**What went wrong :**
I returned the next day to notice system wanted some updates (about 23), I go ahead with the pre-selected choices. On completion the system is wanting to restart (this is what I recall, but for whatever exactly happened, I found myself restarting the computer...).  I wait for PC in shut down mode (not showing any update counter, just shutting down). I give up at 1hr and go for the power off, 4 seconds, all out.

When I reboot, something is different... oh yeah, I don't seem to have any MS Office software (Outlook, Excel, Word, etc)... nothing is opening (well, in fact no icons to click)? The Windows OS is running "fine" and I can traverse Explorer file system, I can load and view web sites with IE (v10 I think?), open and use my Adobe full suite of products, but when I try do anything with MS Office, there's nothing (and I mean, I don't even have any icons anymore or links... just the file extension to try open).

I go into "Install Programs" control panel, and literally the suite is definitely removed from the list, with a single reference of "Microsoft Office Home and Business 2013 - en-us   Ver 15.0.4727.1003"  Ok. I think I'll just uninstall and try re-install Office and then no problems. Uninstalling confirmed no Office software could be located, so removed the item listing. When trying a fresh reinstall from CD, I encounter the following message - "Office needs a newer version of Windows" and "You need a modern version of Windows operating system", in fact "You need Windows 7 (or newer) to install the product".

Hmm... that seemed strange... so I head off down the track that Windows 7 has been damaged.

I remember there used to be "Repair" mode on Windows install disks, so I try that. From windows the install CD operates and shows up "Install Windows 7", but no Repair option. Literally, after a blurry time of attempting various things, I end up "booting" to the install disk, and manage to get the Windows 7 install window with the Repair option showing. I try "repair"...

**The fault is :**
Unfortunately, the details are getting really sketchy this far in, but essentially it said *something* like "You can't repair Windows 7 64 Bit on your 16 Bit windows OS" (definitely it referenced 16-bit OS).

Some time along the way of this whole journey, I encountered an "Error 30015-1025 (216)" - unfortunately, as I didn't think how big this problem was at the beginning, that's all I recorded of the error (I can't recall exactly when?).

---

**Solution/s :**
I am hoping it is some silly registry key, and someone will say "just type 64 Bit into this value, and it will be fine!"... ha ha ha... :-( ...perhaps not?

Before "restore/backup" suggestions... I thought I had my system restore set for my C:\ drive (which is to say - I do have C:\ set ON for system restore points), but there are no system restore points prior to when this occurred. 
I can't roll back my system settings. I have never had an issue on this PC before, and never checked it wasn't operating?.

No, I'm another one, I haven't got a full-back up of my system drive, which I should. My data is safe, but all those little settings, and nuance's of how software is set up, is currently only available I guess from the current PC (if I can rescue the system and software settings?)... but not as an easy go back 1 week and restore the full backup. No. Damn it!   I was thinking of using Windows Transfer to a clean install of Windows 7 on new drive?

Any suggestions welcome.

As mentioned, I am working on my crippled PC quite fine (sort of), other than Outlook (which I'm using web-mail), and working around Word/Excel. My printer is connected fine, I can use Windows Explorer fine, backup software works as I have made a current copy of the whole crippled system okay, I can use Photoshop, Adobe PDF Acrobat, etc... IE is fine, just the system and Office are not liking it.

I have installed other software (such as a KeyFinder to expose my original CD Key), and it installed fine, although it is a very light piece of software anyway.

*Aarrrggghhhh!!*
I guess I am hoping for a quick fix, as opposed to an all-night+ rebuild session of the whole system software and extras. (Or bit less if I can get Windows Transfer to help?).

Cheers to all!